# Date Filter not working in IE - Bootstrap table next Editor

Tags: reactjs, bootstrap-4

Recently we are trying to use the Bootstrap table Next editor in our react project. In our case users use IE to access the application. The date editor is not working in the IE 11 but it works fine in chrome 
even the story book (date editor )  is not working in the IE . is it expected behaviour or any specific IE related settings we need to do. Any pointers?

https://react-bootstrap-table.github.io/react-bootstrap-table2/storybook/index.html?selectedKind=Cell%20Editing&selectedStory=Date%20Editor&full=0&addons=1&stories=1&panelRight=0&addonPanel=storybook%2Factions%2Factions-panel

[Updated]
Tried Custom editor as suggested and fixed the same. 
Raised in Github as well for further implementation in the package
https://github.com/react-bootstrap-table/react-bootstrap-table2/issues/865

Answer (score 0):

IE is not compatible with inputs of type `date`. Check compatibility [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Input/date#Browser_compatibility)

You will have to use a custom date picker if you want to use something similar on IE.